# Multiple definitions for matrix representation of imaginary number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, linear-transformations, rotations

I learnt that multiplying by i can be thought as 90 degree rotation since multiplying by -1 can be thought as 180 degree rotation.
$i*i=-1$ and
$ 90^\circ rotation(90^\circ rotation(x))= 180^\circ rotation(x)$
90 degree rotation require a new plane so invent a complex plane where base unit is i since base can be created by $1\times i$
This idea reminded me of linear transformation.
where $90^ \circ$ rotation(x) = $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot x$
and
$180^ \circ$ rotation(x) = $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\cdot x$
So I thought I could just define
$i=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$and $-1 =\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$
This idea seems to work for the most part
$i \times i = -1, i+i=2i$
But then, I would have to define 
$i = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$and$-1 = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ in order to treat two vector as a complex number.
 
This feels like I am doing something wrong since I have two seporate definitions for what is suppused to be the same thing and to make things worse I have to use different definition for i when I am using different operation on them.
E.g.
$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\end{bmatrix}=-1$ but
$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}=-1$
Here I have a contradiction which depends on which definition I use.
And there are other cases where things just don't make sense in terms of linear algebra e.g.
$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix}=-i$? but
So it feels wrong to represent imaginary number in form of matrices but I don't really know where this confusion comes from.
It might be a bit of an open ended question but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You are mixing vectors and matrices somewhat "randomly".

Comment: Try this: $a+ib \leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{matrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: isn't a vector just 1*2 matrix?(in this case)

Comment: isn't   a+ib↔$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a \end{bmatrix} $just a more general case of 0+i↔$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}$, $i=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$. The problem of having two different definitions still remain?

Comment: Your intuition got you in the ball park, but as you demonstrated in your question representing a complex number as a vector fails to properly encode it’s properties. Try adding and multiplying the matrix representation and see what you get.

Comment: "complex number as a vector fails to properly encode it’s properties" is a very good comment. Since this feels weird. By definition of vector a complex number can be represented as a vector but for some reason it seems to fail to encode it's property on it own.

Comment: What you hit upon is an isomorphism (google that). It sounds like from some of your comments that you might be coming from a programming background, so think of it this way: “if it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, then it’s a duck.”

Comment: I am a programming hobbyist but Isomorphism seems to be the idea here. Thank you very much for the comment I will google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually something called the matrix representation of a complex number.
$$ a + bi = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$$
You can show that multiplying and adding these matrices works will represent the same complex number that we would get by multiplying and adding the complex numbers that the matrices represent. This representation of a complex number is exactly what you derived for your first definition.

As to tackle the two definitions problem, think of the matrices as operations that multiply your vector representation of $a + bi $ as $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} $. The matrix you defined to be $i$ is actually just an operator that will multiply your vector by $i$, and the matrix you defined to be $-1$ is just an operator that multiplies your vector by $-1$.

For more on the matrix representation of the complex numbers with its derivation: https://the-educational-blog.quora.com/Matrix-representation-of-complex-numbers

Hope this clears up some confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the idea to solve the two definition problem is to think of operation and the value to be having two separate definitions where matrix definition is the operation.

Comment: But if I do i+i=2i with matrix  definition of i.you use the matrix as a representation of value of i. Or is this just true as a by product of matrix property and theoretically I shouldn't say. \\ $\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ as a proof of $a+bi+a+bi=2(a+bi)$ \\since I shouldn't treat the matrix as values ?

Comment: And how I have to use two different matrix. $2 \times 2$ for operation and $1 \times 2$ for value feels unnatural to be representing complex number in form of matrix. It feels like a hack where I'm using a method from one matrix and using the attributes from another separate matrix to define a single object with an attribute and method

Comment: To clarify, the matrix representation of a complex number is different than the argument of matrices as operators. You can use that property as a fact that $a+bi + a + bi= 2(a+bi)$ if you are using the matrix representation. A lot of the confusion seems to stem from the fact of how similar the matrix representation of the number itself and the representation of the operation that the matrix could represent are. The matrix representation is derived from the fact that those matrices rotate vectors, while the operator definition is literally the same fact that they rotate vectors.

Comment: I think in the end, vector form and matrix form technically can be used as a value and the operation. But the vector form doesn't have the "rotational" property on it's own but it's basis vector does so you just have to expand and add the basis vector to "encode" the "rotational" property.