# Deduce that $H$ has no elements of finite order other than the identity element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given operation $*$ defined on the set $G$, where $G =\{(a, b)\mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with $a$ and $b$ not both
zero, $(a, b) * (c, d) = (ac + 3bd, ad + bc)$.

Prove that subset $H = \{(a, 0)\mid a \in \mathbb{Q} \land a\neq 0\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. Find $(a, 0)^r$
for $r \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, where $(a, 0) \in H$ and deduce that $H$ has no elements of finite order other than the
identity element.

**Attempt**

I found identity element of $G$ as $(1,0)$ to prove $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ I took $(a,0),(b,0)\in H$ then I proved $(a,0)*(b,0)^{-1} \in H$ so $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Next part, $(a, 0)^r=(a,0)*(a,0)*\dots*(a,0)=(a^r,0)$ so then,

$$(a, 0)^r=(a^r,0)=(1, 0).$$

This implies $a^r=1$ so $a$ can be $-1$ or $1$

If $a=1$ then $(1,0)$ we can neglect it since it is an identity element so we have another element $(-1,0) $ it is also have a finite order but the question is said to deduce there is no elements of finite order other than the identity element.

Is there anything wrong my steps?

Thank you!

Comment: It may help to identify $(a,b)$ with $a+b\sqrt3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you explain it?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931617/matrix-representation-of-complex-number-is-just-a-trick

Comment: @lhf Thank you ..

Comment: What do you get, noname, when you multiply out $(a+b\sqrt3)(c+d\sqrt3)$? and how does that compare with your formula for $(a,b)\times(c,d)$?

Comment: Are you still here, noname?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes ????

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I wrote, "It may help to identify $(a,b)$ with $a+b\sqrt3$." You asked, "can you explain it?" I suggested you multiply out $(a+b\sqrt3)(c+d\sqrt3)$ and compare to $(a,b)\times(c,d)$. So: have you done that? Did you see the point?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes as I think $a+(3)^{1/2}b$ is subgroup of under multiplication is it correct?

Comment: $a+b\sqrt3$ is a number, not a subgroup. The set of all nonzero numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt3$, with $a,b$ rational, is a group under multiplication. It is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of nonzero reals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson got it. so  is G subgroup of multiplicative group?

Comment: $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the multiplicative group of the reals. I suppose that if $F$ is a field that contains the rationals but doesn't contain $\sqrt3$ (for example, ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2)$), then $G$ is a subgroup of the group of all $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ in $F$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you but I don't know much about this topic

Comment: It is not beyond you to prove that the set of all nonzero $a+b\sqrt3$ with $a,b$ rational forms a group under multiplication. The only slightly tricky parts are 1) showing that $a+b\sqrt3\ne0$ unless $a=b=0$, and 2) showing that each element in the set has a multiplicative inverse that's in the set. The first amounts to showing that $\sqrt3$ is irrational. The second just requires you to rationalize the denominator in $1/(a+b\sqrt3)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh got it, how to deduce that H has no elements of finite order other than the identity element?

Comment: You worked out for yourself, and had it confirmed by Shaun, that $H$ does have an element of finite order other than the identity. So why are you asking me how to deduce something that you know to be false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct.

### It is a subgroup.

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test). (Note that I have to show $\varnothing\neq H\subseteq G$.)

Observe that $1\in \Bbb Q$ and $1\neq 0$, so $(1,0)\in H$. Hence $H\neq\varnothing$.

Let $(a,0)\in H$. Then $a\neq 0$, so $a$ and $0$ are not both zero but are both rational. Hence $(a,0)\in G$. Hence $H\subseteq G$.

Let $A=(a,0), B=(b,0)\in H$. Then

$$\begin{align}
AB^{-1}&=(a,0)*(b,0)^{-1}\\
&=(a,0)*(b^{-1}, 0)\\
&=(ab^{-1}+3(0)(0), a(0)+(0)b^{-1})\\
&=(ab^{-1}, 0),
\end{align}$$

which is in $H$ since $ab^{-1}\in \Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ as $a,b\in\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$.

Thus $(H,*)\le (G,*)$.

### The element $(-1,0)\in H$ has order two.

Indeed, if $r\in \Bbb Z^+$, then

$$\begin{align}
(a,0)^r&=\underbrace{(a,0)*\dots*(a,0)}_{r\text{ times}}\\
&=(a^r, 0),
\end{align}$$

since the second argument of $(a,0)$ is zero, meaning $3(0)(0)=a(0)=(0)a=0$.

But $a\neq 0$ by definition of $H$, so, since also $a\in \Bbb Q$, if

$$(a,0)^r=(a^r,0)=e_G=(1,0),$$

then $a^r=1$, meaning $a=\pm 1$ if $\pm r>0$, depending on whether $r$ is odd or even.

### This can be checked directly.

Indeed,

$$\begin{align}
(-1,0)^2&=(-1,0)*(-1,0)\\
&=((-1)(-1)+3(0)(0), -1(0)+0(-1))\\
&=(1,0)
\end{align}$$

and $(-1,0)\in H$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, @noname.

Comment: Is this cyclic group?

Comment: That's a separate question, @noname; please put it in a different post.

Comment: ok thanks. problem is said there is no finite order other than the identity if so is it wrong?

Comment: You're welcome. The element $(-1,0)$ of $H$ has order two, so, yes, it is wrong, @noname.

Comment: Thank you got it!!!