# there's a surjective homomorphism between $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\-3b & a\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}$ $a,b$ reals

Tags: matrices, polynomials, ring-isomorphism

Let $F=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\-3b & a\end{pmatrix} \mid  a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. I want to show $F\simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+3)$. By first isomorphism theorem I just need a surjective homomorphism between $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $F$. But I don't have idea which funtion works.
Can someone give me a suggestion?

Comment: You need to send $x$ to something that squares to $-3Identity$. Can you find $a,b$ such that this happens?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2931659/589

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-3b & a
\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.\tag{1}$$
Any ring homomorphism from $\mathbb R[x]$ that maps the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity is uniquely determined by its action on $x$. So, if $1$ is mapped to the identity matrix and having in mind $(1)$, where would you map $x$, then? If you make the obvious choice, surjectivity will be trivial. Check where $x^2+3$ is mapped.